# Difference between Java2 securitry, J2EE Securiy and JAAS J2C Authentication in Websphere

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, websphere, jaas, java-security

I am wondering whether J2C authentication in Websphere corresponds to Java2 Security or J2EE security.

What is the difference between these two?
While configuring J2C Authentication alias in WAS Console, are we  configuring Java2 Security or J2EE Securiy?

I am prety much confused in these. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Java2 Security and J2EE Security:**

Java 2 Security provides a policy-based, fine-grain access control mechanism that increases overall system integrity by checking for permissions before allowing access to certain protected system resources. `Java 2 Security is independent of J2EE role-based authorization. Java 2 Security guards access to system resources such as file input and output, sockets, and properties, whereas J2EE security guards access to Web resources such as servlets and JSP files.` WebSphere global security includes J2EE role-based authorization, the CSIv2 authentication protocol, and SSL configuration. Java 2 Security can be disabled and enabled independently of WebSphere global security (the Enforce Java 2 Security check box in the Global Security Panel or Server Level Security Panel). However, when WebSphere global security is enabled, by default Java 2 Security is also enabled. Note that Java 2 security can be disabled even though WebSphere Global Security may be enabled.

You can read more about it from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/rzatz/java2.htm).

**J2C authentication**

J2C Authentication uses a Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) pluggable
authentication mechanism to use a pre-configured JAAS login configuration, and LoginModule to map a
client security identity and credentials on the running thread to a pre-configured user ID and password. WebSphere provides container-managed sign-on functionality. The application server
locates the proper authentication data for the target Enterprise Information System (EIS) to enable the client to establish a connection.
Application code does not have to provide a user ID and password in the getConnection call when it is
configured to use container-managed sign-on, and authentication data does not have to be common to all
references to a resource.